# Tkinter: How to update a Canvas create_polygon?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to update a polygon in a canvas when a button is clicked and it's not working.

```
class UpdatePoly(Frame):      

    def __init__(self, master = None):
      Frame.__init__(self, master, width=400, height=700)
      self.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=6,sticky=(N, S, E, W))
      self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=600,background="#ffffff")
      # self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
      self.points = [0,0,0,2,2,4,7,9]
      self.map_ = self.canvas.create_polygon(self.points)
      self.canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")

   def process(self):
     # new co-ordinates
     self.points = [3,4,6,9,4,5,9,0]         
     self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas.create_polygon(self.points))
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are creating a new polygon each time `process` is called. Is that your intention?

Comment: Yes.The intention is to start with a empty canvas then when i call process it plots a polygon on the canvas.

Comment: Then you don't need `itemconfig`. Just call `create_polygon`. The `itemconfig` is useless.